# ngrok installation in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 32-bit

Having trouble to install ngrok in ubuntu, I went to https://ngrok.com/download and download it for ubuntu but it always give binary file which does not allow us to run in ubuntu, Can anyone suggest any other way install it.

Comment: maybe you have to make the file executable first by running `chmod 755 FILENAME`

Comment: The file is executable by default @Wayne_Yux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To install the 32-bit version:

```
wget https://dl.ngrok.com/ngrok_2.0.19_linux_386.zip
unzip ngrok_2.0.19_linux_386.zip
```

After that

`./ngrok`

and you will see this, tested on my 32-bit system.

```
NAME:
   ngrok - tunnel local ports to public URLs and inspect traffic

DESCRIPTION:
    ngrok exposes local networked services behinds NATs and firewalls to the
    public internet over a secure tunnel. Share local websites, build/test
    webhook consumers and self-host personal services.
    Detailed help for each command is available with 'ngrok help <command>'.
    Open http://localhost:4040 for ngrok's web interface to inspect traffic.

EXAMPLES:
    ngrok http 80                    # secure public URL for port 80 web server
    ngrok http -subdomain=baz 8080   # port 8080 available at baz.ngrok.io
    ngrok http foo.dev:80            # tunnel to host:port instead of localhost
    ngrok tcp 22                     # tunnel arbitrary TCP traffic to port 22
    ngrok tls -hostname=foo.com 443  # TLS traffic for foo.com to port 443
    ngrok start foo bar baz          # start tunnels from the configuration file

VERSION:
   2.0.19

AUTHOR:
  inconshreveable - <alan@ngrok.com>

COMMANDS:
   authtoken    save authtoken to configuration file
   credits  prints author and licensing information
   http     start an HTTP tunnel
   start    start tunnels by name from the configuration file
   tcp      start a TCP tunnel
   test     test ngrok service end-to-end
   tls      start a TLS tunnel
   update   update to the latest version
   version  print the version string
   help     Shows a list of commands or help for one command
```

Comment: I'm not sure you have seen https://ngrok.com/download or not because they also provide it for 32 bit

Comment: Sorry. my mistake.

Comment: Do you have an error message after `./ngrok`?

Comment: $ ./ngrok
-bash: ./ngrok: cannot execute binary file

Comment: What's the output of `uname -a; file ngrok`

Comment: Linux arvindv 3.5.0-54-generic #81~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 04:05:58 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
ngrok: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped

Comment: The output of `ldd ngrok`

Answer (score 4):

It works on upper versions but I'm not sure about 12.04:

```
apt-get install ngrok-client
```

Comment: Hmm, seems to output `E: Unable to locate package ngrok-client` for me on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue -- running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64 bit).  I followed the instructions @ [NGROK](https://ngrok.com/download), but couldn't get the command`ngrok http 8080` to respond how I had read it was supposed to.  After reading around and watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZM_qDtSjU-E) YouTube video I found what I needed.  NOTE: The video has no spoken audio, but it does clearly indicate where to install the unzipped executable file and this was the key.

After downloading I ran the following in the terminal from the same directory where the zipped file was located (In my case it was in my home directory):

```
unzip ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip
```

Then I located the executable "ngrok" and ran the following:

```
sudo mv ngrok /usr/local/bin/
```

After completing these steps I was able to run the `ngrok http 8080` and get the expected results (below is the example from the ngrok docs that I am talking about)

```
Tunnel Status                 online
Version                       2.0/2.0
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    http://92832de0.ngrok.io -> localhost:80
Forwarding                    https://92832de0.ngrok.io -> localhost:80

Connnections                  ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Comment: This is an old question and about 12.04 which incidentally is out of support already and lots of things have changed since.